# Spring overwriting controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I provide a highly customisable application to my clients which is working totally by itself. But If one my client wants to overwrite any Controller, I want to replace my implementation by theirs. However just overwriting the controller causes an ambiguous definition of mappings.

I have been using Component Scanning to load beans.

The potential solutions came to my mind are:

1. Using component scanner with excluding by a custom filter? (This seems not so easy)
2. Using a xxxxPostProcessor to remove some beans? (How?)

Any help?

Comment: It really depends on what they want to do, but I'd provide them with an ability to add/swap logic at service level instead of changing the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed these steps:

1. Created a custom annotation: `@Devoted`
2. Created a custom `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`. Iterated already registered bean definitions to find out `@Devoted @Controller's and removed them.

Based on a request I will provide implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your Question properly,

You can differ implementation by changing URL to particular Implementation name

Say Telecom is interface and AirtelImpl and RelianceImpl are Controllers then

Your request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/airtel/doBilling")
@RequestMapping(value= "/reliance/doBilling")
```

In this way, Implementation flow will differ.